# XGBoost: Is it possible to predict multiple labels and calculate their MAPE?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

As far as I'm concerned, XGBoost supports multi-class prediction with objective functions such as softmax.

In my case, I'd like it to output several labels (float numbers) and minimize the MAPE of them. Is it viable? What should I do to make that happen? (Say, how do I construct a DMatrix with multiple labels at first hand.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    data = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5]])
    label = numpy.array([[0.2,0.1], [0.3,0.4]])
    dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data, label=label)
    param = {'gamma':2.0,'nthread':8, 'max_depth':15, 'eta':0.000000003, 'silent':1, 'objective':'multi:softprob', 'eval_metric':'auc' ,'num_class':105}
    bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round)
```

Comment: While this might provide an answer to the question, some explanation is required. Please update the question with some explanation of how and why this solution works.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.